# Prove if $f$ is continuous and $X$ is compact, then $f(X)$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove if $f$ is continuous and $X$ is compact, then $f(X)$ is bounded.

That's what I wrote:

Suppose $f$ is not bounded. Then, $f^{-1}([k,\infty])$ is nonempty, where $[k,\infty)$ is a closed set. Otherwise, $k$ would be an upper bound. Thus, $\cap_{k=0}^{\infty}f^{-1}([k,\infty))$ is nonempty closed-chain-compact since $f$ is continuous and $[k,\infty)$ is closed.

I want have a contradiction here but I cannot see it. Anyone can help me with it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you define what exactly $f$ and $X$ are? I'm assuming $X$ is a general topological space and that $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes. Actually, $X=\{0\}\cup\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}.\}$ And $f: X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function.

Comment: @Kelan, what do you mean by closed-chain-compact? $\{[k,\infty)\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ is descending chain of closed sets and hence so is$\{f^{-1}([k,\infty))\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$. But why compact?

Answer (score 2):

This proof works for any compact topological space $X$ and continuous $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$.

Consider the sets $U_n=(-n,n)\subset \mathbb{R}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$. These sets are all open and cover $\mathbb{R}$ therefore the collection $\{f^{-1}(U_n)|n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}\}$ is an open cover of $X$. Since $X$ is compact this cover must have a finite subcover.

Let $m$ be the maximum integer such that $f^{-1}(U_m)$ is in this finite subcover. Since $U_i\subset U_j$ for $i< j$ it follows all other elements of the subcover are actually subsets of $f^{-1}(U_m)$. But since the whole of $X$ is covered it follows that $f^{-1}(U_m)=X$. Therefore $f(X)\subseteq U_m$ and hence $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different method, but you have to assume $X$ is a metric space: I am assuming $f\colon X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Try taking a sequence in $f(X)$ that goes off to infinity, so $f(x_{n})\rightarrow \infty$. We know the sequence $(x_{n})$ will be in $X$, so will have a convergent sub-sequence, also call this $(x_{n})$. But since $f$ is continuous, $f(x_{n})\rightarrow f(x)\in \mathbb{R}$, which is a contradiction since we assumed $f(x_{n})$ diverged.

Comment: This answer assumes that $X$ is [sequentially compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space) rather than compact.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is continuous the image of a compact set under $f$ is compact. A compact set in $\mathbb R$ (or any $\mathbb R^n$ for that matter) is closed and bounded (see [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem)). Hence $f(X)$ is bounded.